# MySQL Updating the same table with a before trigger

Tags: mysql

I am a student that is currently learning MySQL, and is currently having troubles with using Trigger to check on the insert.

I have the following table *classes*

```
CREATE TABLE classes
        (Class        CHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY,
         cType        CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
         Country      VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL,
         numGuns      INT(2) NOT NULL,
         Bore         INT(2) NOT NULL,
         Displacement INT(6) NOT NULL);
```

The question asks me to write the following attribute based checks on this database:

- The number of guns must be between 8 and 12.

My trigger currently looks like this

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER chkGun
BEFORE INSERT ON classes
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF NEW.numGuns >= 8 AND NEW.numGuns <= 12 THEN
      UPDATE classes
      SET numGuns = NEW.numGuns;
  ELSE 
      SET NEW.numGuns = NULL;
  END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I keep getting the error message

```
Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'classes' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.
```

I know from the error message above that I can't update the same table that the trigger is currently using.
Is there anyway to update the attributes in the same table?

Answer (score 0):

Don't do the update if number of guns are correct, just let it pass. If number of guns are too low or too high set it to null.

The trigger fires before the normal update and any changes you make to NEW.* will be the ones that gets written.